# Firebase: Clear user data after signing out with FirebaseAuth.signout()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-recyclerview

In my app I sign out from the action menu in my Main activity with:

```
FirebaseAuth.singout()
```

I am trying to clear the user data, but my fragment holding the data inside a viewpager doesn't trigger the authLister to clean up the adapter when there is no longer a current user.

```
authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                setupRecyclerView();


            } else {
                // User is signed out
                adapter.cleanup();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: what you do in adapter.cleanup(); ?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel .cleanup() is a FIrebaseRecyclerView method, it does exactly that. I think my issue is getting a reference to the state change from the menu signout.